# Is full wave rectified AC, without a smoothing capacitor, okay for switching a DC solenoid and a DC relay?

Tags: capacitor, ac, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, ac-dc

I have a circuit where the 24V AC secondary voltage of a transformer is full wave rectified to DC.

The only parts that this circuit is connected are some 24VDC solenoids and a 24VDC relay. The solenoids and relay are controlled by digital pins of a microcontroller through the optocoupler circuit below by another secondary of the transformer (9VAC), regulated at 5VDC.

[image]

If I put a smoothing capacitor after the diode bridge the 24VAC voltage gets too close to 35VDC after the capacitor. Then I'd have to use a voltage regulator that accepts more than 35VDC as input to get back to 24VDC.

Could I get rid of the capacitor and the voltage regulator, so the AC-DC conversion would get close to 21.5VDC, and not 35VDC (not smoothed) and then use this 21.5VDC to power this circuit  above that then drives the relay and solenoids?

Could this circuit above work normally with this non-smoothed voltage at the "6-28VDC Power Supply"?

Comment: I would worry about switching 35 VDC with a 24 VDC rated relay.

Comment: Adding a series resistor to the relay and using smoothed DC should work well.

Comment: note a relay coil is an inductor and does some *current* smoothing of its own! it's also a current-driven device - current matters more than voltage - if current is smooth and voltage isn't, the relay should behave fine. Same for solenoids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is full wave rectified AC, without a smoothing capacitor, okay for switching a DC solenoid and a DC relay?

Yes.

The average DC voltage would be only 90% of the RMS voltage (24 * 0.9 = 21.6 V in this case).

[image]

It would work because the 'pull-in' voltage of the relay would be maximum 70% of it's rated voltage and it's 'drop-out' voltage minimum 10%.

Likewise with the solenoid.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, certain types of 24VDC relays will operate on full-wave rectified 24VAC, however they don't pull in as smartly as with DC, so contact life may be compromised.

You could consider creating a supply with a bridge rectifier and a small value capacitor (uF or tens of uF) that would charge to the peak voltage almost when unloaded, then collapse when the load is applied, after tens of milliseconds. The capacitor has to be of a type that doesn't mind a relatively high ripple voltage (so not too much heating from the ripple current and ESR).

Answer (score 5):

24VAC = 24VRMS.  The *peaks* of that AC sinusoid are \$\cdot \sqrt{2}\$ or 24VRMS*1.414 = 33.9Vpeak-peak.

For a full-wave rectifier, all of the AC wave (all 33.9V of it, from peak-to-peak) is rectified to DC, minus the voltage drop of the diodes, so about 1.4V or so.  So with a little load you'd likely get about 32VDC from rectified 24VAC.

Now a modern multimeter measuring this (with smoothing capacitor installed) will correctly report 32VDC.  But remove the capacitor and it might report *24VDC* - why?

If the cap is removed, the output is no longer a steady DC value. Instead, it is pulsating DC - repeatedly going from 0V to 32V and back. A "True RMS" multimeter will perform a true RMS measurement on that pulsating DC and report it as 24VDC(RMS), *because 24VAC and this pulsating 24VDC will do the same amount of work to a load.*

You can test this against a function generator and oscilloscope.  Set the function generator to output a 1.0VAC sine wave at 60Hz and look at it on the 'scope.  It's peak-peak voltage will be 1.414V.  Measure that with the multimeter and it should read 1.0VAC(RMS). *The peaks must be higher than 1.0VDC to do the same amount of work as 1.0VDC because the voltage is not constant and is even 0V twice-per-cycle*.

Check out [Falstad's simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-rectify.html) of half-wave and full-wave rectifiers.  Note it shows the voltage source as "Max = 5V" but that is *peak* - if you hover the mouse over it, this is 3.536VRMS.  So these sources are really "3.536VAC(RMS)."

Answer (score 5):

There is a misunderstanding of [RMS vs. peak voltage of AC](https://testguy.net/content/%20270-Peak-vs-Average-vs-RMS-Voltage). For a 24 VAC sine wave, the RMS voltage (think of it as similar to an "average" voltage) is 24 VAC, but the **peak** voltage is √2, ~1,414, x 24, or ~34 V peak. In addition to being a higher voltage than that for which the relays are designed, the pulsating nature (100 or 120 variations/sec) of the power may cause relay chatter or overheating of the relay, due to eddy currents.

You already have 34 V of pulsating directly from the power supply (minus a volt or two dropped in the rectifier). If you want to change that to 24 VDC, the **simplest** way might be to use a [choke input filter](https://electronicscoach.com/choke-filter.html) with a capacitor. You'd need to know the current draw of the relays to select a suitable value for the inductor and capacitor. That said, though this is the *simplest* answer, for high currents, a physically large choke would be needed, adding weight and expense. A voltage regulator might be a *better* solution.

Answer (score 2):

No. After you rectify your voltage you'll essentially invert the negative part of the sine wave, making it positive.

As you only invert it, it's not DC voltage.

When you rectify the voltage, Vout is going to be Vout=Vin x sqrt(2) no matter what, so for 24V x sqrt(2) vout=33.94V, as you are getting 24V that's to be expected.

You really need to regulate the voltage with the capacitor. Voltage regulators are really cheap and easy to implement, such as LM7824 would do the job.

I simulated your idea and pasted the image with capacitor vs no capacitor.

The yellow curve shows the output voltage withouth capacitor and blue with capacitor, you can see the difference.

[image]

Comment: Note that with a relay or solenoid, what matters is not voltage but current, and depending upon the resistance and inductance of the coil, the current waveform may look very different from the voltage waveform.  If the inductance is high enough, the current might never fall to zero even though the voltage would go negative by a couple of diode drops.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answer says, most of relays will work and On-Off solenoid also. If you apply PWM to solenoids, take care with the frecuency, as the supply will be a 100 Hz pulsating DC and can be an issue in regulation.

Where I see a problem is the power MOSFET LR7843, as VDS maximum is 30 V. When the signal is off, the MOSFET will get voltage peaks over this limit. You need to change to a MOSFET with VDS > 40 V. Also coupler PC817 max collector-emitter voltage is 35 V, close to voltage peaks.

Comment: Thanks! Although it's possible to be done, after all these answers I guess It's better to change my circuit and include a voltage regulator to make things more predictable...